# Does simple_form work with paperclip validates_attachment_presence?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, simple-form

I have a model with a paperclip attachment called avatar, the model uses validates_attachment_presence to ensure avatar is present.  simple_form didn't seem to pick this up and didn't render the form with an asterisk to indicate avatar is a required field.  I added an additional validates_presence_of :avatar and simple_form picked up the field but now it won't add the error class when the user doesn't select an avatar.  Has anyone got simple_form working with paperclip attachements?

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to add a presence validation as well as the attachment_presence:

```
validates :avatar, attachment_presence: true, presence: true
```

This will correctly show the asterisk with simple form and validate the presence of the file correctly.

Comment: Works for me. Be sure to use `f.input` (simple_form syntax) and not `f.file_field` (rails form helper syntax).